# Jigsaw hot reload

Tags: java, java-9, java-platform-module-system, hot-code-replace

As I understand Java 9 modules are all about encapsulation and shading.

*Will they be about hot code reload too?*

As for me it looks like the future is not supposed to be ever implemented. Because it neither follow OSGI way (all Java 9 modules use single classloader) nor JRebel way (because that means per-class hot reload, not per-module).

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate, but do you not find [what you're looking for as an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20263366/1746118)? Primarily - [JEP-159](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/159)

Comment: @nullpointer thank you a lot! Very usefull reference. I think you have answered my question :)